# Pull data from a SQL table into a DataTable based on a parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, tuples

I'm expanding a class in a project where I need to pull down specific data from a SQL table into a DataTable. Before, the data was calculated and modified all inside a SQL proc but I have amended this so that the calculated data in passed into a new table instead. Now, I'm writing a method that will pull this data out of the database based on the ID value of it.

A lot of this code was written by another developer and he has a thing for tuples which I don't know too much about and confuse me a little bit. Logic wise, I've done something similar but I've only ever pulled down a whole table and not just a specific row.

This is my first pass at the method:

```
 public DataTable ReadSqlTableToDataTable( List<Tuple<string, string>> parameterValueMappings, DataTable dt)
    {
        string query = "SELECT *  FROM dbo.Mytable WHERE IdValue= ";

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_config.ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query + parameterValueMappings, conn);


            using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 600;
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
        }                           
        return dt;
    }
```

Then I use it a class like so:

```
private readonly IDbRepository _repo;
private readonly DataTable _revisedDatabTable;
private List<Tuple<string, string>> _commandParameters;
private readonly int _batchId;

public FooClass(IDbRepository repository, DataTable revisedDatabTable, int batchId) //pass in structure
    {
        _repo = repository;
        _revisedDatabTable = revisedDatabTable;
        _batchId = batchId;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {

        _commandParameters = new List<Tuple<string, string>>
        {
            new Tuple<string, string>("@IDValue",_idValue.ToString() )
        };


        _repo.ReadSqlTableToDataTable(_commandParameters, _revisedDatabTable);
    }
```

Before finally calling the class like this:

```
 new FooClass(_repo, dtRevisedData, idValue).Execute();
```

The `idValue` is read in via a file and is thrown into my new SQL table.

Now, when I run this I get nothing back. My table has data in it, so I know that isn't the problem. I have a feeling the issue is in how I'm using the tuple. Have I set it up correctly? If not, what is it I have done wrong?

Comment: put a break on ReadSqlTableToDataTable and check your query - im thinking it doesnt read how you think it does

Comment: What you expect to get when you use "+" operator with `string` and `List<Tuple<string, stirng>>` on line `new SqlCommand(query + parameterValueMappings, conn);`?

Comment: @Fabio I would expect it to be an integer value to complete the SQL statement i pass in. As my SQL query is incomplete

Answer (score 2):

You are misusing the `SqlCommand`. Instead of concatenating strings you should specify query as string and pass all the parameters using `SqlCommand.Parameters`.
See the sample [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx).

In your case it should be smth like this. No tuples, no concatenations.

```
string query = "SELECT *  FROM dbo.Mytable WHERE IdValue = @IDValue;";

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query , conn);
command.Parameters.Add("@IDValue", SqlDbType.Int);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not breaking the values into a comma separated string and use IN instead of = ?

```
string allTuperValues = string.Join(",", parameterValueMappings.Select(t => 
string.Format("{0}", t.Item2)));
string query = "SELECT *  FROM dbo.Mytable WHERE IdValue IN(" + allTuperValues 
+ ")";
```

Comment: Not optimal approach and bad advise, you should always use `SqlParameter`. Keep safe from sql injection and execute queries more effectively(by reusing complied query plans)